# Dynamically Generating Pandas Views

Tags: python, pandas, functools

I have several classes that all reference the same pandas dataframe, but only part of the data frame is relevant to each class.  I also want to make it easy to access the relevant rows without using the advanced indexing as it gets repetitive due to number if levels in the index.  As a result, I wrote code that generates partial functions so that each class can view its slice.

```
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import dateutil.relativedelta as rd
import datetime as dt

class baz(object):
    pass

groups = ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar']
items = ['x','y', 'x', 'y']
diff = rd.relativedelta(years=1)

dates = [dt.date(2013,1,1) + (diff * shift) for shift in xrange(4)] * 2
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([groups, items], names=['groups', 'items'])
values = np.random.randn(4,8)

data = pd.DataFrame(values, index=index, columns=dates)

def view_data(group, item):
    return data.ix[group, item]

foo = baz()
bar = baz()

# I use partial because I want lazy evaluation
foo.x = partial(view_data, 'foo', 'x')
foo.y = partial(view_data, 'foo', 'y')
bar.x = partial(view_data, 'bar', 'x')
bar.y = partial(view_data, 'bar', 'y')

foo.x()
```

However, I would prefer if the reference did not have to look like foo.x()[date] but could instead look like foo.x[date].

As a result, I created a decorator that would wrap the function and return the value.

```
def execute_func(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner()

foo.x = execute_func(partial(view_data, 'foo', 'x'))
foo.y = execute_func(partial(view_data, 'foo', 'y'))
bar.x = execute_func(partial(view_data, 'bar', 'x'))
bar.y = execute_func(partial(view_data, 'bar', 'y'))
```

My concern is that I will not always get the current state of the dataframe.

Is this the right way to go about achieving my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I personally would suggest you wrap your DataFrame in an object like so:

```
class MyDataFrameView(object):

    def __init__(self, df):
        self.data = df

    def x(self):
        return self.data.ix['foo', 'x']

    def y(self):
        return self.data.ix['bar', 'y']
```

you use it like so:

```
df = MyDataFrameView(data)
df.x()
```

you can go further and add the methods as properties if it makes more sense intuitively.

```
@property
def y(self):
    return self.data.ix['bar', 'y']
```

it is essentially doing the same thing like you do now, but it's more straightforward object oriented programming and - at least in my opinion - a lot better to understand.

you can always access your dataframe like so:

```
df.data
```

or then, you could implement more pandas methods directly on your View object, for example:

```
@property
def ix(self):
    return self.data.ix

def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.data.__getitem__(key)
```

so you object behaves more like a DataFrame.

note that is not really "dynamic". If you want a truly dynamic way, you could use the **getattr** method to implement that as well

```
def __getattr__(self, attr):
   #code that "routes" to do the right thing given attr
```

This pattern is generally called composition, and my favorite way of implementing your "problem"

Comment: An alternative is to add x as an attribute to  all DataFrames with `@property def x(): ...; pd.DataFrame.x = x`, subclassing DataFrame directly is also an option...